# Unable to change line-height of element inside heading

Tags: css

I have a heading (`h1`) containing a `small`. The `small` is styled to `font-size: 60%`. Everything looks fine until the `small` is too long to fit on one line and line breaks.

What happens then is that the line-height of the `small` is *way* too high. Changing it to 1 or < 1 makes no difference. Even changing it to an exact `px` value does nothing.

How can I reduce the line-height of my `h1 small` properly?

http://jsfiddle.net/2SDLq/

```
    <h1><small>Here's a long small text preceding the normal sized text in this heading</small><br>Normal Size</h1>

    h1 {
    font: bold 30px/1.2 "HelveticaNeue-Light","Helvetica Neue Light","Helvetica Neue",Helvetica,Arial,"Lucida Grande",sans-serif;
    font-size: 3rem;
}

h1 small {
    font-size: 60%;
    font-weight: normal;
    line-height: 10px; /* Does nothing */
}
```

Answer (score 11, accepted):

You need to add `display:inline-block` to the small. Elements that are inline do not take on line-height.

Updated jsfiddle http://jsfiddle.net/2SDLq/14/

Answer (score -1):

Since:

- headings are by default block elements
- inline-block value is not supported in lte IE7 (although these versions are thankfully no longer commonly used)
- you're placing the `small` element in a separate line

you can set the `display` property to `block`:

```
h1 small {
    display: block;
    font-size: 60%;
    font-weight: normal;
    line-height: 10px;
}
```

Apart of being able to set the line-height property for `small`, you can also get rid of unnecessary 
 tag and set the gap between the heading text and small with padding and/or margin